# List of words within List as character

Tags: python

I have a file having data in form

```
Your
Name
```

I am reading the file and want to convert the data in the list but each word as a separate list in the form of words. I tried the below code

```
def return_list():
    a1_filename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()
    a1_file = open(a1_filename, 'r')
    grade= []
    line = a1_file.readline()
    while (line != ''):
        for words in line:
            b = words.rstrip('\n')
            grade.append([b])
        line = a1_file.readline()
    return grade
```

My output is:

```
[['Y'], ['o'], ['u'], ['r'], [''], ['N'], ['a'], ['m'], ['e'], ['']]
```

But what I am trying to get is

```
[['Y','o','u','r'], ['N','a','m','e']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to add a temporary list in your loop. That said we can make a change here to help close the file. In your example you never call `a1_filename.close()` so maybe you don't know that you need to close the file when you are done. To avoid forgetting about this it is best to use a `with open` statement as it will auto close after completion.

Try this:

```
def return_list():
    a1_filename = 'test_file'
    grade = []  # set up main list to be returned before the open statement.
    with open(a1_filename, 'r') as a1_file:  # use with open instead so you properly close file.
        line = a1_file.readline().strip()  # Strip whitespace here before while statement.
        while line != '':
            temp_list = []  # used to store a list of each word before appending to main list grade.
            for char in line:
                if char != '\n':
                    temp_list.append(char)
            grade.append(temp_list)  # Append temp list to main list.
            line = a1_file.readline()

    return grade


print(return_list())
```

Results:

```
[['Y', 'o', 'u', 'r'], ['N', 'a', 'm', 'e']]
```

If you would like a short and simple version we can use a fun one liner to clean up the new lines and at the same time generate our list of list. That said if it affects readability I would avoid one liners but if you can understand the one liner just by reading it then they are a fun and clean option to use:

```
with open('test_file') as f:
    print([[char for char in word] for word in f.read().splitlines() if word])
```

Or:

```
with open('test_file') as f: print([[char for char in word] for word in f.read().splitlines() if word])
```

Results:

```
[['Y', 'o', 'u', 'r'], ['N', 'a', 'm', 'e']]
```

Comment: It showing me ['N', 'a', 'm', 'e', '\n']] at the end but it helps

Comment: @AHF I also added a one liner example that you can use to shorten your code.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.  The main one is that you're trying to build a two-level data structure with a single-feature construction.  Instead, build the list of letters you want, and then append that list to your master list.
The second problem is that you're using `append` on a list, which adds the entire list structure.

```
while (line != ''):
    chars = []
    for words in line:
        b = words.rstrip(' \n')
        chars.append(b)
    grade.append(chars)
    line = a1_file.readline()
```

Comment: Above code give me output with extra `(' ')` for example '[['Y','o','u','r', ' '], ['N','a','m','e', ' ']]' If I use strip for (' ') then it start showing '\n'

Comment: Then `strip` spaces as well.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the problem.

```
with open('path/filename') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

lines = [[char for char in line] for line in list(filter(None, lines))]
```

Comment: As this almost works for the OP's need why are you creating a function for `[char for char in word]`? the same can be done in your other one liner like this `lines = [[char for char in line] for line in lines]`. So there is no need for an additional function. You need to be able to remove the empty list that is returned when there is a new empty line in the file.

Comment: Removing empty lines will be an easy fix. Will update the answer

Comment: Updated and fixed.

Comment: Interesting use of `filter()` Do you know if there is an advantage or difference vs `[[char for char in line] for line in lines if line]`?

Comment: For this case, no. But using filter can help in adding more conditions for future cases like what if line only contains a `space` or `blank`. In that case `if line` will return `true` but with filter you can remove that as well although it will need some additional code.

Comment: Hum. Well in my example I do `with open('test_file') as f: print([[char for char in word] for word in f.read().splitlines() if word])` and blank rows and rows with spaces are handled fine. Would filter allow to exclude anything I want though? Say I want to exclude specific words.

Comment: Yes, you can do that by replacing the `None` in filter by a function that will return boolean. This way you can filter out anything.

Comment: By blank row, I mean a row with just a space and nothing else. In the code in your comment, `if word` will return true as there is a character even though it is simply a `space`

Comment: cool I may start using filter in the future for some of my work.

Answer (score 1):

I put your example file into `text.txt`, here is an easier approach with `map` follows a `filter` function, it's ugly but works in one line:

```
with open("test.txt",'r') as f:

    data = [*filter(lambda x: x!=[] ,
        map(lambda x: list(x.strip("\n")),
        f.readlines()))]
```

Comment: Not quite. You have to get rid of the empty list being produced as well. Currently this results in `[['Y', 'o', 'u', 'r'], ['N', 'a', 'm', 'e'], []]` if there is a new line in the file without a 3rd word. That said I do like the use of `map` here I have not seen this before.

Comment: You're right, didn't consider the edge case, I've edited my approach to make it more robust.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close - just gotta make sure that each list gets appended to a master list, so that you have your list of lists.

```
def return_list():
    a1_filename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()
    a1_file = open(a1_filename, 'r')
    list_of_lists=[]
    grade= []
    line = a1_file.readline()
    while (line != ''):
        for words in line:
            b = words.rstrip('\n')
            grade.append([b])
        list_of_lists.append([grade])
        line = a1_file.readline()
    return list_of_lists
```

Answer (score 0):

`grades.append([b])` is going to wrap `b` in a list and then append it. That's not quite what you're looking for - instead, why not make a new list entry for each line?

```py
grade=[]
line = a1_file.readline()

while(line != ''):
  subgrade = []

  for words in line:
    b = words.rstrip('\n')
    subgrade.append(b)

  grade.append(subgrade)
  line = a1_file.readline()

return grade
```

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension offers a more succint and pythonic solution. Just update the loop:

```
while (line != ''):
    grade += [list(w.rstrip('\n')) for w in line.split(' ')]
    line = a1_file.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
for words in line:
```

to

```
for words in line.split():
```